# Why is the mismatch between declaration and definition not raising error during compilation?

Tags: c++, compilation, function-declaration

I have two source files, `main.cpp` and `math.cpp`, along with a header file `math.h`. The code is as follows:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << add(5, 10);
    return 0;
}


// math.cpp
#include "math.h"
int add(int x)
{
    return x;
}


// math.h
int add(int x, int y);
```

I have intentionally created a mismatch between the declaration and definition of `add`.

Since I have included `math.h` in `math.cpp`, I expect the compiler to raise an error when I run the command `clang++ main.cpp math.cpp -c`. Instead, the compilation succeeds.

I understand that the mismatch will eventually cause an error at link-time but can someone explain why the compilation is succeeding in this case?

Comment: Functions can be overloaded.

Comment: "I understand that..." do you know about translation units?

Comment: This is can be detected only in `C`. In `C++` you can have function overloads, so multiple functions with same name can exists.

Comment: You can make it error if you turn on more warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/o1Ejhqeh7

Comment: There is no reason for error here. You may elevate missing prototype warning for GCC, that' got nothing to dowith C++ and but issue is that is' a little finncky feature. In C++ function definitions and prototypes have same syntax and same effect. A proper linter (static analizer) may detect this  if the function was defined outside of scope of usage.

Comment: Incidentally, `math.h` is a header in the standard C++ library (inherited from C); you'll save yourself some headaches down the road if you use a different name for your header. If you change your project layout and your include paths get messed up you might end up getting the standard header instead of yours, and that will lead to confusing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is legal:

```
#include <iostream>

int add(int);
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int add(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << add(1, 2) << '\n'; // calls two-argument version
    std::cout << add(3) << '\n';    // calls one-argument version
    return 0;
}
```

It's simply function overloading. If the single-argument version isn't used it doesn't have to be defined:

```
#include <iostream>

int add(int);
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

// int add(int x) {
//     return x + 1;
// }

int main() {
    std::cout << add(1, 2) << '\n'; // calls two-argument version
    // std::cout << add(3) << '\n';    // calls one-argument version
    return 0;
}
```

Putting the declaration of `int add(int)` into a header doesn't change the meaning of the code.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a second source file

```
// math2.cpp
#include "math.h"
int add(int x,int y)
{
    return x;
}
```

or not. The compiler does not know (nor care) while compiling `math.cpp`.

> Since I have included math.h in math.cpp, I expect the compiler to raise an error when [...]

When you compile `math.cpp` then the declaration does not match the definition, but there is no reason to complain about it. `math.h` could declare a `void foo()`  and `math.ccp` could define a `void bar()` and there would also be no reason for the compiler to complain about that.

Answer (score 2):

In math.cpp you implement `int add(int x)` which happens to be different from `int add(int x,int y)` defined in math.h. From your point of view, that may be wrong, but from the C++ point of view this is correct, because C++ allows function overloading.

Now in main.cpp you use `add(5, 10)`. For the compiler this is OK because in math.h you define `int add(int x,int y)`, which basically tells the compiler "there is a function `int add(int x,int y)` implemented somewhere", so there is no problem for compiling.

Finally at link time the linker needs to generate the code that actually calls `int add(int x, int y)` but there is no such function and therefore it complains.

---

The compiler doesn't care if you compile both files together or separately.

This:

```
$ clang++ main.cpp math.cpp -c
```

is exactly equivalent to this:

```
$ clang++ main.cpp -c
$ clang++ math.cpp -c
```

Answer (score 2):

Within `main.cpp`

```
// main.cpp
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << add(5, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

the included header `math.h` declares the function `add` with two parameters

```
// math.h
int add(int x, int y);
```

Thus this statement where the function is called

```
    std::cout << add(5, 10);
```

is correct.

The name `add` is declared with the required number of parameters.

Within `math.cpp` there are declared two overloaded functions

```
// math.cpp
#include "math.h"
int add(int x)
{
    return x;
}
```

namely

```
int add(int x, int y);
```

and

```
int add(int x)
{
    return x;
}
```

One of the funtions is also defined. So the compilation unit is correct.
There is nothing wrong. An error can occur at phase of the linkage.